# Cross-reference tables, figures, etc.?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, cross-reference

I'm trying to use cross-reference in a report to place links to tables, figures, and appendices.  But they are not available under the Reference type.  How do I get them to appear so that they are easily referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following figure on how to locate your figures and tables in the MS Word document. Follow the numbers in the picture and you will get to it.
[image]

In Step 3, When you select the Figure / Table as per your requirement, in Step-4 your choices for selection will be a list of figures or tables that you have already created in your document.

You have to select the figure or table and from the drop down menu (numbered as 4 in my picture) select the type of reference you would like to place in your document.
*A bit of trial and error will help you learn on what option gives you what information*